# OTel to debug inside one service?

Tags: go, open-telemetry

I have a complex application written in Go.

Unfortunately it does too many requests to a third party API.

We hit rate-limiting.

Now I want to know: Which source code lines do the api calls?

We can provide a custom http client with a custom transport to count the
amount of api calls we do.

But the number of api-calls is not enough.

I would like to know: which source code lines make the api call?

I could use [debug.Stack](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/debug#Stack) to create a Stacktrace.

How can I use OpenTelemetry to get Stacktrace, so that I can monitor which source code lines create the outgoing http requests?